# Handling Pop-under ads in Website using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract and post some data in a site in some intervals say 1 hr. But the site is showing pop-under ads (new tab opens for ads) in random intervals. How could i prevent/handle those ads? The site is captcha protected so i cannot close and open the site every time.

Comment: What is the exact question: *How could I prevent adds?* or *How could I handle ads?*? The solutions might be totally different, so it will be hard for you to select answer to accept. Also share your current code and how you tried to solve the issue

Comment: Both will work as long as i am able to extract and post in the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this piece of code in intervals until you have completed what you need. Set `MainWindow` to the window you start with before ads start popping up:

```
MainWindow = driver.current_window_handle

def CloseNewWindows(driver, MainWindow):
    Windows = driver.window_handles
    for window in Windows:
        driver.switch_to_window(window)
        if MainWindow != driver.current_window_handle:
            driver.close()
```

Comment: Ads are displayed in new tabs not new window. Its pop-under ads not pop-up.

Comment: That is what it's for. Did you try and run the code?

Comment: Any new `window` or `tab`, that is a child process of the main driver, will be checked and closed. Please try testing code before stating answer is incorrect.